# How to import or fetch Confluence pages in Backstage?

Tags: confluence, backstage

I'm quite new to Backstage and I'm playing around in order to understand it better. But there's this business requirement that requires me to import or fetch the existing documents from Confluence and add it to Backstage. Any suggestions on how to achieve this? Like a plugin or something. I did see some plugins that adds a search function to Backstage that will redirect you to the Confluence page but that's not what I'm looking for.

Comment: Hi @Ritwik1711, did you manage to make any progress with this?

Comment: Hey @AndyDavies, I couldn't figure it out and the company decided to ditch it for now.